# Using a build process like Grunt inproduction

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, build-process

I have been build a very large nodeJS app for the past 8 or so months and until recently how our folder structure was setup has worked out fine. To make the whole system more extendable and "enterprisey", I'm reworking our whole build process.

I've gotten the revamped filesystem looking like this:

```
 |
 +-- Gruntfile.js
 |    
 +-- pub
 |  |  
 |  +-- dist
 |  |  |  
 |  |  +-- assets
 |  |  |  |  +-- images/fonts/etc..
 |    
 +-- sites
 |  |  
 |  +-- site1
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- assets
 |  |  |  |  +-- images/fonts/etc..
 |
 |  +-- site2
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- assets
 |  |  |  |  +-- images/fonts/etc..
```

Each of the sites (`site1, site2`) are on their own repo and only pulled in if needed. This allows me to not repeat any code and have different sites inherit from each other. When the app starts up I just need to pass `NODE_SITE site1` and in development grunt takes care of all the building/copying all the assets for me putting all the correct files in `dist` so I can use them on my site.

Since Grunt shouldn't be used in production what could be an alternative? Or just using a `grunt copy` task ok?

Comment: Grunt is primarily a build tool. Since when do you not use build tools for production? You may run a grunt task locally to create a zip file or something that you can just upload to each site, or whatever, if you want to avoid running Grunt tasks on a production server. Or do it as part of a CI server build.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt should be run as a part of the rest of the build process. So if the default task of your gruntfile, corresponds to the deve environment, create a task for prod environment. That "prod" task, should minify JS,CSS and other stuff, copy the resources to the desired location and thats it. Run once along with the rest of the build script.